# WatchOS 2 and NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, watchkit, watchos-2

I have an iPhone app that exchange data with a device over the LAN and send those to the WatchKit extension using the SendData method. All is working fine, but when the iPhone is suspended/sleeping I noticed that the NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred for the input stream is fired up with this message:

**Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 \"Socket is not connected"**

It seems like the iPhone is losing its wifi connection. Do i suppose that when suspended the iPhone can't keep its socket connections opened?

Comment: Do you mean locked by suspended ?

Comment: Anyway be sure that you've configured your app to support back-grounding

Comment: Back-grounding is enabled. And as suspended I mean both lock screen and black screen.

Comment: I've found the cause: iphone turn off (or something similar) wifi in suspend mode to save battery life. That's annoying that there is not a setting to keep wifi on everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the end the problem is the WiFi connection of iphone 5, that when suspended or locked is dropped. I've found somewhere that this functional mode has been changed by Apple in iphone 6, so I should try with that.